# VB6 is application running as administrator

Tags: windows-7, vb6, windows-vista, uac, administrator

Is there any way of finding out if the application is running as administrator?

If this involves a COM call, I'm not really fussed, anything that works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IsUserAnAdmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an easy call and seems perfectly reliable for use in VB6 programs.  It seems to work fine even in Win8.

Note that it reports whether the process is running with admin rights, not whether the user is in the Administrators group.

Declaring it this way it should work all the way back to Windows 2000:

```
Private Declare Function IsUserAnAdmin Lib "shell32" Alias "#680" () As Long
```

Comment: This is what I used in the end! I wasn't sure if it would have worked in pre-vista windows, so I went with an alternative route in C# and called it using interop

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`CheckTokenMembership()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the admin SID. I've not tried calling this from VB though.
(Taken from the Inno [`IsAdminLoggedOn()`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/CmnFunc2.pas) function.